# Creating and deleting divs using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a few JavaScript functions designed to add and remove HTML divs to a larger div. The function init is the body's onload. New lines are added when an outside button calls NewLine(). Divs are removed when buttons inside said divs call DeleteLine(). There are a few problems with the code though: when I add a new line, the color values of all the other lines are cleared, and when deleting lines, the ids of the buttons, titles, and line boxes go out of sync. I've gone through it with the Chrome debugger a few times, but each time I fix something it seems to cause a new problem. I would greatly appreciate some input on what I'm doing wrong.

```
function init()
{
    numOfLines = 0; //Keeps track of the number of lines the Artulator is displaying
}

function NewLine()
{
   var LineBoxHolder        = document.getElementById("LineBoxHolder");
   numOfLines               += 1;
   LineBoxCode              += "<div class = 'Line Box' id = 'LineBox" + numOfLines + "'>" //The code is only split onto multiple lines to look better
                            + "    <h6 id = 'Title " + numOfLines + "' class = 'Line Box Title'>Line " + numOfLines + "</h6>";
                            + "    <p>Color: <input type = 'color' value = '#000000'></p>"
                            + "    <input type = 'button' value = 'Delete Line' id = 'DeleteLine" + numOfLines + "' onclick = 'DeleteLine(" + numOfLines + ")'/>"    
                            + "</div>";
   LineBoxHolder.innerHTML += LineBoxCode;
}
function DeleteLine(num)
{
    deletedLineName     = "LineBox" + num;
    deletedLine         = document.getElementById(deletedLineName);
    deletedLine.parentNode.removeChild(deletedLine);
    num++;
    for ( ; num < numOfLines + 1 ; )
    {
        num++;
        var newNum                              = num - 1;
        var changedLineName               = "LineBox" + num;
        var changedHeaderName          = "Title" + num;
        var changedButtonName           = "DeleteLine" + num;
        var changedButtonOC              = "DeleteLine(" + newNum + ")";
        var changedLine                       = document.getElementById(changedLineName);
        var changedHeader                  = document.getElementById(changedHeaderName);
        var changedButton                   = document.getElementById(changedButtonName);
        var changedLine.id                   = "LineBox" + newNum;
        var changedHeader.innerHTML = "Line" + newNum;
        var changedHeader.id               = "Title" + newNum;
        var changedButton.setAttribute("onclick",changedButtonOC);
        var changedButton.id                = "DeleteLine" + newNum;
    }
    num--;
    numOfLines = num;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having a hard time debugging your code because of your approach. You are "marking" various elements with the IDs you construct, and using the IDs to find and address elements. That means that when things change, such as line being deleted, you have to go back and fix up the markings. Almost by definition, the complicated code you wrote to do something like that is going to have bugs. Even if you had great debugging skills, you'd spend some time working through those bugs.

**Do not over-use IDs as a poor-man's way to identify DOM elements**. Doing it that way requires constructing the ID when you create the element and constructing more IDs for the sub-elements. Then to find the element again, you have to construct another ID string and do `getElementById`. Instead, use JavaScript to manage the DOM. Instead of passing around IDs and parts of IDs like numbers, pass around the DOM elements themselves. In your case, you don't need IDs at all.

Let's start off with `DeleteLine`. Instead of passing it a number, pass it the element itself, which you can do my fixing the code inside your big DOM string to be as follows:

```
<input type='button' value='Delete Line' onclick="DeleteLine(this.parentNode)"/>
```

So we have no ID for the line element, no ID for the element, and no ID within the onclick handler. `DeleteLine` itself can now simply be

```
function DeleteLine(line) {
{
  line.parentNode.removeChild(line);
  renumberLines();
}
```

We'll show `renumberLines` later. There is no need to adjust IDs, rewrite existing elements, or anything else.

Since we no longer need the ID on each line or its sub-elements, the code to create each element becomes much simpler:

```
function NewLine()
{
   var LineBoxHolder = document.getElementById("LineBoxHolder");
   numOfLines        += 1;

   var LineBoxCode   = "<div class='LineBox'>" +                                      
                     + "  <h6 class='LineBoxTitle'>Line " + "numOfLines + "</h6>"
                     + "  <p>Color: <input type='color' value='#000000'></p>"
                     + "  <input type='button' value='Delete Line' onclick= 'DeleteLine(this.parentNode)'/>"    
                     + "</div>";
   LineBoxHolder.innerHTML += LineBoxCode;
}
```

The only remaining work is to fix up the titles to show the correct numbers. You can do this by just looping through the lines, as in

```
function renumberLines() {
  var LineBoxHolder = document.getElementById("LineBoxHolder");
  var lines = LineBoxHolder.childElements;
  for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    var line = lines[i];
    var h6 = line.querySelector('h6');
    h6.textContent= "Line " + (i+1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I voted to close because the question *is* too broad, but will answer anyway on a few points to... well, *point* in the right direction.

1. `var changedButton.setAttribute("onclick",changedButtonOC);` This is not a variable declaration. Omit the `var`.
2. `for ( ; num < numOfLines + 1 ; ) { num++; ...` The correct form here would be simply `for (; num < numOfLines + 1; num++) { ...`.
3. Instead of incrementing (`num++`) then decrementing (`num--`) around the loop, why not just use the right math?

See:

```
for (; num < numOfLines; num++) {
  ...
}
```